# using $regex in mongodb aggregation framework in $group

Tags: regex, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Consider the following example:

```js
db.article.aggregate(
  { $group : {
      _id : "$author",
      docsPerAuthor : { $sum : 1 },
      viewsPerAuthor : { $sum : "$pageViews" }
  }}
);
```

This groups by the author field and computes two fields.

I have values for $author = FirstName_LastName.
Now instead of grouping by $author, I want to group by all authors who share the same LastName.

I tried $regex to group by all matching strings after the '_'

```js
$author.match(/_[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/)

db.article.aggregate(
  { $group : {
      _id : "$author".match(/_[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/),
      docsPerAuthor : { $sum : 1 },
      viewsPerAuthor : { $sum : "$pageViews" }
  }}
);

also tried the following:

 db.article.aggregate(
  { $group : {
      _id : {$author: {$regex: /_[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/}},
      docsPerAuthor : { $sum : 1 },
      viewsPerAuthor : { $sum : "$pageViews" }
  }}
);
```

Answer (score 6):

Actually there is no such method which provides this kind of functionality or i could not find the appropriate version which contains it. That will not work with $regexp i think : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/regex/ it is just for pattern matching.

There is an improvement request in the jira : https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6773

It is in open unresolved state. 
BUT

in github i found this disscussion: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/pull/336

And if you check this commit: https://github.com/nleite/mongo/commit/2dd175a5acda86aaad61f5eb9dab83ee19915709

it contains more or less exactly the method you likely to have. I do not really get the point of the state of this improvement: in 2.2.3 it is not working .

Answer (score 4):

Use mapReduce: it is  the general form of aggregation. This is how to proceed in mongo shell:
Define the map function

```
var mapFunction = function() {
  var key = this.author.match(/_[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/)[0];
  var nb_match_bar2 = 0;
  if( this.bar.match(/bar2/g) ){
    nb_match_bar2 = 1;
  }
  var value = {
    docsPerAuthor: 1,
    viewsPerAuthor: Array.sum(this.pageViews)
  };

  emit( key, value );
};
```

and the reduce function

```
var reduceFunction = function(key, values) {

  var reducedObject = {
    _id: key,
    docsPerAuthor: 0,
    viewsPerAuthor: 0
  };

  values.forEach( function(value) {
    reducedObject.docsPerAuthor += value.docsPerAuthor;
    reducedObject.viewsPerAuthor += value.viewsPerAuthor;
  }
  );
  return reducedObject;
};
```

run mapReduce and save the result in map_reduce_result

```
>db.st.mapReduce(mapFunction, reduceFunction, {out:'map_reduce_result'})
```

query map_reduce_result to have the result

```
>db.map_reduce_result.find()
```

Answer (score 4):

`$group` combining `$addFields` and `$arrayElemAt` works for me (version ≥ 3.4).

Say we have following data in collection `faculty`, database `school`:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ed5a59b1febc4c796a88e80"), "name" : "Harry_Potter" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ed5a60e1febc4c796a88e81"), "name" : "Edison_Potter" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ed5a6231febc4c796a88e82"), "name" : "Jack_Potter" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ed5a62f1febc4c796a88e83"), "name" : "Alice_Walker" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ed5a65f1febc4c796a88e84"), "name" : "Bob_Walker" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ed5a6731febc4c796a88e85"), "name" : "Will_Smith" }
```

Following can group each document by the last name:

```
db.faculty.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      lastName: {
        $arrayElemAt: [ { $split: ["$name", "_"] }, 1 ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$lastName",
      count: {$sum: 1}
    }
  }
])
```

Running result is:

```
{ "_id" : "Potter", "count" : 3 }
{ "_id" : "Walker", "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "Smith", "count" : 1 }
```

The trick I used is to add a field named `lastName`. Based on what you have for the `name` field, it can be split into an array by `_`. Last name is at index 1 and first name at index 0.

Reference

[$addFields (aggregation)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/)

[$arrayElemAt (aggregation)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/)

Answer (score 3):

A possible workaround with the aggregation framework consists in using $project to compute the author name. However, it is dirty as you need to manually loop through the different first name sizes:

Here, we compute the field name as the substring after the '_' character, trying each of its possible position (this is why there is a chain of $cond), and fallbacking in returning the whole $author if the first name is too long:

http://mongotry.herokuapp.com/#?bookmarkId=52fb5f24a0378802003b4c68

```
[
{
    "$project": {
        "author": 1,
        "pageViews": 1,
        "name": {
            "$cond": [
                {
                    "$eq": [
                        {
                            "$substr": [
                                "$author",
                                0,
                                1
                            ]
                        },
                        "_"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "$substr": [
                        "$author",
                        1,
                        999
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "$cond": [
                        {
                            "$eq": [
                                {
                                    "$substr": [
                                        "$author",
                                        1,
                                        1
                                    ]
                                },
                                "_"
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "$substr": [
                                "$author",
                                2,
                                999
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "$cond": [
                                {
                                    "$eq": [
                                        {
                                            "$substr": [
                                                "$author",
                                                2,
                                                1
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        "_"
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "$substr": [
                                        "$author",
                                        3,
                                        999
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "$cond": [
                                        {
                                            "$eq": [
                                                {
                                                    "$substr": [
                                                        "$author",
                                                        3,
                                                        1
                                                    ]
                                                },
                                                "_"
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "$substr": [
                                                "$author",
                                                4,
                                                999
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "$cond": [
                                                {
                                                    "$eq": [
                                                        {
                                                            "$substr": [
                                                                "$author",
                                                                4,
                                                                1
                                                            ]
                                                        },
                                                        "_"
                                                    ]
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "$substr": [
                                                        "$author",
                                                        5,
                                                        999
                                                    ]
                                                },
                                                "$author"
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
},
{
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$name",
        "viewsPerAuthor": {
            "$sum": "$pageViews"
        }
    }
}
]
```