# group by on a part of string from a field rather than the whole field in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I would to like to know whether the group by is possible for a particular substring of a field   in mongodb rather than grouping it by the whole field itself.

Eg:
I have a field PostId containing values abcde:123,abcde:456, abcde:789.....field name is **PostId.**
Can i group by just the string **abcde** rather the whole field that is (abcde:123).

I tried the below query, its grouping it by the whole postid field. But i require it to just group by the part of string in postId.

---

```js
db.noundata.aggregate({
  $match: {
    EntityId: 334,
    SubProductId: 1,
    AdjScore: {
      $gt: 0.0
    },
    NounWord: 'foot'
  }
}, {
  $group: {
    _id: {
      PostId: "$PostId"
    },
    NounWeightage: {
      $sum: 1
    }
  }
}, {
  $sort: {
    AdjScore: -1
  }
}, {
  $limit: 10
})
```

**What i require is, is there a possible way to group by on regex rather  than the whole field**

thanx

Comment: did you try grouping like 
**_id: {
      PostId: {$regex : "$PostId"}    }** I'm not sure about the result. Just an idea

Comment: possible duplicate of [using $regex in mongodb aggregation framework in $group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14785815/using-regex-in-mongodb-aggregation-framework-in-group)

Comment: @MustafaGenç That would match the entire field right not just the regex part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [$substr](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/substr/) in aggregation framework within a $project to extract the needed part of the string. After you can use it to group.

One example:

```
> db.collection.aggregate({$project:{a_whole:'$a',a_substr:{$substr:['$a',2,3]}}})
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "a_whole" : "abc:123",
            "a_substr" : "c:1"
        },
        {
            "a_whole" : "ab:123",
            "a_substr" : ":12"
        },
        {
            "a_whole" : "abcd:123",
            "a_substr" : "cd:"
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```